# Cocos2d: usage of references vs getChild performance

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, cocos2d-iphone

I am unsure on which approach will give me a better performance:

I have a GameScene class in which I tend to allocate a objects and then add them as childs to the class with a tag. This approach is used in many examples I studied but I am not sure if it is the best when I need to frequently access to child objects (e.g. update a score label in the GameScene). In those cases I am wondering if it would be a better approach in terms of performance to declare a pointer to those frequently used object and use it to access the object instead of getting the child by tag.

**Is it more efficient to use getChildByTag or accessing those objects via their pointer?**

```
As example I provide a label that I frequently update during the game, e.g. it could be the score label:

@interface GameScene : CCLayer 
{
    CCLabelTTF *frequentlyUsedLabel;
}

//Implementation

-(id) initWithId:(int)sceneId
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        //..code
        frequentlyUsedLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hearths:" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:20];
        [self addChild:frequentlyUsedLabel]; 
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you know you need to improve performance ?  If you dont, stick to your pattern, improves code readability, thus maintainability. The answer to your question as stated : getChildByTag is garanteed to take more time than using a pointer. So it is not a question of whether your performance will improve, but by 'how much' , hence my opening remark : if you dont need to improve, dont change your code.

Comment: Cool, the thing is that I need to access those labels often (almost every other frame) and for this reason I thought the answer to 'how much-frequently' would be 'very much-frequently' but I was not sure and wanted to ask to you guys if you have similar approaches-problems-experiences.. but thanks for your answer, it helps as I wasn't sure that getChildByTag was slower!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write code that is easy to maintain.
2. Anything worth optimizing is worth measuring.

Time how long it takes to render a frame using both methods. Ask yourself if it matters.

The extra memory overhead is a little more difficult to measure (in particular, Cocos2D *might* be using a clever allocator that is more efficient if your CCLayer subclass doesn't declare any extra ivars). My take is that 4 bytes is the amount of memory used by a *single pixel*.

With UIKit, I personally find it much easier to use ivars than to worry about tag uniqueness (especially when reusing code in different apps or using a view in multiple places). This is especially the case with ARC, since you no longer have to worry about getters/setters/retain/release.

Comment: thnks,I will try and will post some results.I need to get the hang on using Instruments to measure the performance and as soon as I will have done this I'll post some update..I shall also understand properly how Cocos2D and iOS work together to draw each frame (e.g.whether there is a draw call for the entire scene based on the absolute z level or whether the calls are based on the node hierarchy and hence the number of child nodes (as well as the number of z levels) are directly proportional to the number of calls..PS:Will wait a day or two to mark as accepted to see if anyone else contributes

Comment: My main point was that storing the sublayers in ivars is probably easier to code and maintain than using tags. The only reason *not* to is the increased memory usage, but at 4 bytes, the difference isn't worth worrying about.